# Axios - Display returned error from validation is [object Object]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

In my api I have:

```
$request->validate([
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);
```

And then I catch the error on `axios with`:

```
.catch(error=>{
    console.log("Error: " + error.response.data.errors)
})
```

However it will give me: `Error: [object Object]`

If I purposely enter a `username` that is already on the database, and then change the catch to

```
.catch(error=>{
    console.log("Error: " + error.response.data.errors.username)
})
```

It will display `Username is already taken` which is a good thing.

This means that I have to manually specify the `error.response.data.errors.<x error>` in order to display the message since if I put `data.errors.username` and then the email is the problem in the validation, the console will say `Error: undefined` which makes sense since there is no `data.errors.username` but `data.errors.email`.

Is there a way I could access and display the returned error without manually specifying it? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify(error.response.data.errors)`?

Comment: Yes. It would display `{"username":["The username has already been taken."]}`

Comment: if this does the job, could i post it as answer?

Comment: I actually want to take in the message within the `data.errors`

Comment: try `console.log(Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat().join())`

Comment: That worked. Thanks and God bless! :)

Comment: you're welcom, i post the answer with details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to show the errors object values try to get them using `Object.values(errors)` which return some arrays, then use the `flat()` method to make one array from them and finally join that values using `join()` method as follows :

```
  console.log(Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat().join())
```